Ocultar un div luego de transcurrido un tiempo
Estoy tratando que al abrir el modal se muestre con javascript Mensaje1 por unos 4 segundos y que luego (Mensaje1) desaparezca, quedando solamente Mensaje2.
Estoy usando Bootstrap 5.
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Prueba</title>
         <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="modal fade" id="demo" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    
                    <div class="text-center text-danger fw-bold" id="mensaje">Mensaje1</div>
                    <div class="text-center text-primary">Mensaje2</div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <!-- Show modal -->
        <script>
            var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('demo'), {})
            myModal.toggle()
        </script>
        
        <!-- Mostrar Mensaje por tiempo -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                $('mensaje').fadeOut(1500);
            },400);
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>

Traté quitando el id del div de Mensaje1 pero tampoco funciona.
EDITADO: En el ejemplo publicado dejé por error el código en jQuery, pero ahora al utilizar bootstrap 5 ya no debería utilizarse jQuery sino javascript puro.
Encontré el siguiente código que he reducido y que oculta y muestra un texto al hacer click en un botón.
¿Cómo puedo hacer eso en el código de mi modal pero que automáticamente oculte Mensaje1?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

  <div id="myDIV">
    This is my DIV element.
  </div>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>


No está demás recordar que para Bootstrap 5 es prácticamente innecesario usar jQuery. O una de dos: o incluís jQuery en tu código (ya que lo de mostrar el mensaje por tiempo está en jQuery), o convertís tal fragmento de código a JS.

Una animacón css puede servir, en el ejemplo hay 3 variaciones:

la primera se aplica agregandole una clase via javascript ( sin jQuery )
la otra ya trae la class en el html. Es la misma animación pero mas rápida; si la página tarda en cargar te la perdes.
la tercera es una variación de la primera, pero se activa a partir de que el modal se muestra ( enganchando al event shown.bs.modal)



.ocultar {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: ocultarAnimado 5s forwards;
}

@keyframes ocultarAnimado {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  75% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    /* display: none; */
  }
}

.ocultar.rapido {
  opacity: 1;
  animation: ocultarAnimado 0.75s forwards;
}
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Prueba</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="modal fade" id="demo" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="text-center text-danger fw-bold" id="mensaje">Mensaje1 ocultar on load + 4s</div>
        <div class="text-center text-warning fw-bold" id="ocultarAlAbrir">ocultar 4s luego de abrir el modal</div>

        <div class="text-center text-primary">Mensaje2</div>
        <div class="text-center text-secondary text-small fw-thin ocultar rapido">Pestañeaste</div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Show modal -->
  <script>
    const modalDemo = document.getElementById('demo')
    var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(modalDemo, {})
    myModal.toggle()

    /* agregar la clase ocultadora a abrir el modal */
    modalDemo.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      const mensaje = document.getElementById('ocultarAlAbrir');
      mensaje.classList.add('ocultar');

    })
  </script>

  <!-- Ocultar Mensaje por css onLoad -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

      const mensaje = document.getElementById('mensaje');
      mensaje.classList.add('ocultar');

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>




Interesante solución.

agregado una opción para que la clase "ocultadora" se agregue sólo cuando se abre el modal

Ya lo vi con mas detalle y estabas muy cerca de lograrlo, te falto incluir jquery y la referencia a el id con el signo #mensaje y listo


 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <title>Prueba</title>
             <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="modal fade" id="demo" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        
                        <div class="text-center text-danger fw-bold" id="mensaje">Mensaje1</div>
                        <div class="text-center text-primary">Mensaje2</div>
    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-eKhayi8LEQwp4NKxN+CfCh+3qOVUtJn3QNZ0TciWLP4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
            <!-- Show modal -->
            <script>
                var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('demo'), {})
                myModal.toggle()
            </script>
            
            <!-- Mostrar Mensaje por tiempo -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#mensaje').fadeOut(1500);
                },400);
            });
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>




Si, olvidé comentar que no se debe utilizar jQuery. He editado la pregunta.
